# SELECT query to collect results from two tables

Tags: mysql, select

I have a simple query that selects the latest due date of a book from a 'loan' table.

I am using the following query;

```
SELECT duedate, no
FROM loan 
WHERE duedate =
  (SELECT duedate FROM loan ORDER BY duedate DESC LIMIT 1);
```

The query results show the latest date and the 'no' of the person that took the book. 
I am now looking for a way to modify the query to also display the name of the person. The name is however in a different table called 'student' but the 'no' from the 'loan' table from the results in the query above needs to match the name of the person from the 'student' table.

The 'no' from the results will match up with a name in the 'student' table as the 'no' is also in the 'student' table on the same row as the name.

How would I modify my query to display the name as well as the 'no' and 'duedate'?

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Try yo improve the readability of question. It will help you to get ans quickly and correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT loan.duedate, loan.no, student.name FROM loan
INNER JOIN student ON loan.no = student.no
ORDER BY loan.duedate DESC LIMIT 1
```

Try this..! Gud luck :)

Answer (score 1):

**Use JOIN;**

```
SELECT loan.duedate, loan.no, student.name FROM loan
INNER JOIN student ON loan.no = student.name
```

Learn more about [MySQL JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

And I don't understand why you have used **subqueries** in your already SQL query.
It also can be done as,

```
SELECT duedate, no FROM loan ORDER BY duedate DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A [join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) let you combine columns of different tables. You need to define the matching column (in your case `no`, in most cases this is an ID) in the `on` clause.

```
SELECT loan.duedate, loan.no, student.name 
FROM loan
left JOIN student on loan.on = student.on
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a `join`.  This solution assumes the student name column is named "name".

```
SELECT loan.duedate, loan.no, students.name FROM loan 
LEFT JOIN students ON loan.no=students.no 
ORDER BY loan.duedate;
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

For performance purposes, you will most likely want to create indexes on the `no` column in both tables.